# Why can't Selenium find dynamically added DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, capybara

I added a DOM element (a link) with jQuery.  I can see the element in Firebug, but for some reason Selenium can't find it.  What is going on here?

Note: there is no AJAX involved, so the DOM element is added almost immediately.

== EDIT ==

Here's some code (using jQuery) that appends a link to the end of the document:

```
$element = $("<a id="foo" href="#"></a>");
$element.appendTo($("body"));
```

I'm using Capybara (with Selenium) to find the link and click it, like so:

```
find("#foo").click
```

I was having no problems with Capybara or Selenium until I started adding elements to the DOM with jQuery.

Comment: Post some code exhibiting the issue.

Comment: How you're trying to locate? Without that no answer is possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use waitForElementPresent in your test code.