# Testing Angular dynamic page content (ng-if) with Geb

Tags: javascript, angularjs, geb

I am trying to test if an Angular ng-if element is visible or not using Geb. So far I've attempted to test if the displayed property is true or false as follows.

Angular:

```
<article ng-if="!condition" class="bar foo ng-scope">Text to Display</article>
```

Geb UI Module:

```
unselectedErrorText { $(class: "bar foo ng-scope") }
```

Test:

```
assertThat(unselectedErrorText.displayed).isFalse()
checkBox.value()==false
assertThat(unselectedErrorText.displayed).isTrue()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
The required page content 'unselectedErrorText - SimplePageContent' is not present
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I had missed was that the Angular code generates dynamic page content. [Geb(through the underlying selenium) will just have the initial DOM before any JavaScript manipulation is performed.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16298674/2220216)

I solved this using the [waitFor](http://www.gebish.org/manual/0.7.0/javascript.html#waiting) method provided by Geb.

```
checkbox.value(false)
waitFor("quick") {
    assertThat(unselectedErrorText.displayed).isTrue()
}
```

Any further, more comprehensive explanation is very much appreciated!

Comment: I do the same for pretty much any dynamic content.